# having trouble using random for 2 of my own functions for connect4

Tags: random, lambda

I'm making Connect 4 for an assignment and have been told that for the start of the game, a `random` 2x3 size of obstructed cells must be placed at the start of the game. I thought I could simply used the random choice function to randomly choose one of my defined blocks of obstructed cells. Instead the program prints both of them, creating a 2x4 obstructed cell. Can anyone help??
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z4bm.png)
<kbd>([https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vq[2]3q.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vq%5B2%5D3q.png))</kbd>
`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqT8F.png)`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq0Kd.png)
the output is as follows; a single 2x3 block of '0s' should be printed, instead of this:
[`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey60J.png)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2wdF.png)

I've tried everything help

Comment: I suggest you upload your images to SO and made them visible

Comment: Please add your code as a [mre] & as text in the body of your question. See also [ask]

Comment: Hi, I just tried editing it to embed the photos but I need 10 reputation. Is there a way you can upvote this question; giving me 10 points so I can then embed the photos?